# If reviews are fine

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

I frequently visit the "review" tab of stackoverflow, but if I approve a review, how does anyone else know? I don't know if when at higher rep I will be able to approve a suggested reviewed answer/question, but have heard nothing of it. There should be a way to say that a edit is fine so people don't keep editing it. I think there should be an "Approve" button next to the "Make Edits" button. This will make life easier and less frustrating than when I have to scroll through lots of pages to find an inadequate question/answer.

Comment: Do you mean to say that once you've suggested an edit, nobody else should be able to edit before yours is accepted/rejected? I think this is already the case. (I might not have understood your question though, since it's not really clear to me)

Comment: @Bart I mean its annoyin if lots of people keep editing the same post even if it was already fine

Comment: So you're saying that at a certain point, a question should be marked as "good" after which nobody should be able to edit it anymore? If that's the case, I would disagree.

Comment: @OutlawLemur The vast majority of posts receive < 4 revisions ([two standard deviations from the mean of 1.7 revisions )](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70254/average-edits). This includes the original post, owner edits and rollbacks, so its unlikely that any particular post will get a lot of revs. Is there a specific post that you're observing getting a lot of annoying edits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as there is room for improvement, people should be able to edit (or suggest edits for) a question. If edits are seriously too minor, those reviewing suggested edits can of course reject them as such.

This does not stop anyone with enough rep from editing minor details as they see fit, but I don't particularly see this as a problem that would need a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Review is a tool to monitor new posts so "mistakes" can be easy corrected.

As far as I know, it is not a tool to approve or disapprove posts. The community uses the vote button for that part.

Comment: Im not saying that it is  a good answer necissarly, so I wouldnt vote it up, just that it is grammatically correct